# getEditResponseUrl -> blank form for some rows

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using the `getEditResponseUrl` method for quite some time. However now in the list of over 400 entries some of the urls which are generated end up with a blank form instead of the previously added content. Any idea on solving this?

```js
function linksmaken() {
  var urlCol = 64; // kolom nr 64 begint met 1
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0)); 
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());  
  }

  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);   
  }

  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

Comment: Please share a sanitised copy of your sheet

Comment: You seem to have several undeclared variables in that function.